# why this inside object literal equals to another object

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
var testObject = new TestObject();
testObject.init();

function TestObject() {
    this.init = function() {
        var uiCtrlDescriptors = {
            "htmlElem": "elem",
            "controller" : new Controller(this.htmlElem)
        }
    }    
}
```

and I don't understand why `this` is equal to `testObject` inside this line:

```
"controller" : new Controller(this.htmlElem)
```

instead of being equal to `uiCtrlDescriptors` object?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how `this` works.  Whenever you do:

```
obj.some_function();
```

then `some_function` runs with `this` set to `obj`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. So inside the object literals `this` will always be `testObject` ?

Comment: the object literal has nothing to do with it; you're using `this` inside the function assigned to `init`, and then you call `testObject.init()`.

Comment: Yes, but you can [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4js6/) that `this` changes depending on what object literal it is used inside.

Comment: correct.  but your code doesn't have a function inside an object literal.  it has an object literal inside a function.